# espresso checking text in a recycler view header added as item decoration

Tags: android, canvas, android-recyclerview, android-espresso, item-decoration

so I have a recycler view, and I needed to add items to it as sections or headers. I'm achieving this using recycler views ItemDecorations onDrawOver method, so writing it to a canvas and inserting it like this

```
 private void drawHeader(Canvas c, View child, View headerView) {
    c.save();
    if (sticky) {
        c.translate(0, Math.max(0, child.getTop() - headerView.getHeight()));
    } else {
        c.translate(0, child.getTop() - headerView.getHeight());
    }
    headerView.draw(c);
    c.restore();
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    super.onDrawOver(c, parent, state);

    if (headerView == null) {
        headerView = inflateHeaderView(parent);
        header = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.title);
        fixLayoutSize(headerView, parent);
    }

    CharSequence previousHeader = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < parent.getChildCount(); i++) {
        View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final int position = parent.getChildAdapterPosition(child);

        String title = sectionCallback.getSectionHeader(position);
        header.setText(title);
        if (!previousHeader.equals(title) || sectionCallback.isSection(position)) {
            drawHeader(c, child, headerView);
            previousHeader = title;
        }
    }
}

private View inflateHeaderView(RecyclerView parent) {
    return LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.request_sticky_header, parent, false);
}
```

I'm now writing tests for this but it crashes with 'No views in hierarchy found matching: with text:' I can't see the text in the heirarchy and I'm wondering if its because the layout is drawn to the canvas, can anyone help me with a way to check if the view has been added?

btw the view is there i can see it i just want a test thats proves it, if its not possible ill rely on manual checking and screenshots many thanks

Comment: Test code would be useful here

Comment: Thanks @denys but ive scrapped this and changed to switching view holders in the adapter